# How to provide space between two groups in SWT

Tags: swt

I have created three groups under one composite and I want to give equal space between three groups. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You can set a GridLayout which has horizontalSpacing property to the composite. 
(e.g. ```GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().spacing(horizontalSpacing, verticalSpacing).applyTo(composite);```)

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you want. Show us a [mre] and describe what it should look like.